# How to upload files and name them with file type?

Tags: php, html, file-upload

hey guys so I created a website that you can upload books to and display them as a list I have a form to input the name of the book and the file type and I want them to display as the name and file type (on the same line) example (nameofabook epub) but when I try is display them it shows up like (nameofabook
new line epub) here's my code thank you

```
<?php
if (isset($_FILES['file']) && isset($_POST['name'])) {
    $file = $_FILES['file'];

    $file_name = $file['name'];
    $file_type = $file['type'];
    $file_tmp = $file['tmp_name'];
    $file_size = $file['size'];
    $file_error = $file['error'];

    $file_ext = explode(".", $file_name);
    $file_ext = strtolower(end($file_ext));

    $allowed = array("mov", "avi", "mp4", "epub", "pdf"); //The extensions you allow

    if (in_array($file_ext, $allowed)) {
        if ($file_error === 0) {
            if ($file_size <= 2097152) {    //the maximum filesize
                $file_destination = ''.$file_name;  // If ' ', the file will be placed in this directory
                if (move_uploaded_file($file_tmp, $file_destination)) {
                    echo $file_destination;

                    $fp = fopen('book_list.txt', "a");
                    fwrite($fp, $_POST['name']. "|||" .$file_destination."\n");
                    fwrite($fp, $_POST['type']. "|||" .$file_destination."\n");
                    fclose($fp);

                } else {
                    echo "An error has been encountered while moving your file!";
                }
            } else {
                echo "Your file is too big!";
            }
        } else {
            echo "An error has been encountered while uploading your file!";
        } 
    } else {
        echo "You can't upload files of this type!";
    }
}
?>
```

if anyones curious heres my html for the upload page

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Upload a Book</title>
        <link href = "style2.css" type = "text/css" rel = "stylesheet" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            Name: <input type="text" name="name" required/> 
            Type: <input type="text" name="type" required/> 
            File: <input type="file" name="file" required/> 
            <input type="submit" value="Upload" />
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sorry mister coder! where do you store books and how do you display books ?

Comment: using a file named book-list.txt to display and store it I host my website on 000webhost so in that directory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Firstly...**
Don't upload files directly in your site! You should upload them with an API, outside, in a cloud storage. In this case, you can use [Cloudinary](https://cloudinary.com) . So, you don't need to think much about the files uploaded. Again, you can show them easily!
Don't store information like names and others(without the file) in a text file. Storing them in a MySQL database is the best way to do so.

**Secondly...**
Use different inputs for collecting book names and other information so that, you can display and modify them easily.

**Thirdly...**
Please give the code you are using for displaying data

I'm a **Homo sapiens** So I can write anything wrong. Please forgive me for that.